# Can we create a new controller by extending another controller class in the Spring 3.0?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a requirement in the my application that I need to extend a controller class by extending the another controller class.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/bulkTrade.htm")
    public class TradeController extends ApplicationObjectSupport {
    // methods and fields.
    }
```

I need to create a new controller that should extends the TradeController. By simply using the extends keyword is not working. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you also need add the @Controller and @RequestMapping annotation in your class.

The @Controller make your class's instance as a bean in application context

Comment: the @Controller make your class's instance as a bean in application context.